# iOS User Email Password Input Box

Tags: ios, xcode

How can one create an Email and Password input box similar to this image in XCode. I do not see a multiline text box in XCode.

[image: Here]
<sub>(source: [favbulous.com](http://favbulous.com/resources/uploaded/ioslogin/9.jpg))</sub>

Comment: You can use a grouped `UITableView` and use core graphics to provide effects like corner radius etc or you can choose to go with two `UITextField`s with a background image mocking the similar view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with UITableView.
In Storyboard make a TableView with Content: Static Cells and Style: Grouped.
In the "Table View Section" set Rows to 2 and place an Textfield with a placeholder.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is this also possible similarly ![here](http://favbulous.com/resources/uploaded/ioslogin/11.jpg)

Comment: It is a simple UITableView with UITableCells